Is there a precalculus algebraic proof for $0<y<x\implies\ \sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{x-y} > \sqrt[3]{x+y} - \sqrt[3]{x}$?
Here is a precalculus-level purely algebraic proof that $f(x):\sqrt{x}$ is strictly concave for $x>0,$ that is, $0<y<x\implies\ \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-y} > \sqrt{x+y} - \sqrt{x}:$
$$y>0\implies y^2>0\implies x^2 > x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$$
$$\implies x > \sqrt{x-y}\sqrt{x+y}$$
$$\implies 2x > x + \sqrt{x-y}\sqrt{x+y}$$
$$\implies 4x > 2x + 2\sqrt{x-y}\sqrt{x+y} = (x-y) + (x+y) + 2\sqrt{x-y}\sqrt{x+y} = \left(\sqrt{x-y}+\sqrt{x+y}\right)^2$$
$$\implies 2\sqrt{x} > \sqrt{x-y}+\sqrt{x+y} $$
$$\implies \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-y} > \sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{x}. $$

I am looking for a similar/analagous precalculus-level proof for $g(x):=\sqrt[3]x$ is strictly concave, that is, $0<y<x\implies\ \sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{x-y} > \sqrt[3]{x+y} - \sqrt[3]{x},$ using only the following algebraic manipulations:

Doing the same operation to both sides of the equation, including squaring or cubing, so long as the logic makes sense.
Expanding brackets or factorising.
You can also split into different cases, such as $y\geq x/2$ or $y<x/2.$

No:

AM-GM.
Induction.
Binomial theorem.
etc.

For my scratch work with the square root case above, I started with the expression I was trying to prove, $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-y} > \sqrt{x+y} - \sqrt{x},$ I squared both sides, and took it from there, until I got to an equation I already knew was true. I tried this with the cubed root example but didn't manage.
$$\sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{x-y} > \sqrt[3]{x+y} - \sqrt[3]{x}$$
$$ 2\sqrt[3]{x} > \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} $$
$$ 8x > (x-y) + (x+y) + 3 \left(\sqrt[3]{x-y}\right)^2\sqrt[3]{x+y} + 3\sqrt[3]{x-y}\left(\sqrt[3]{x+y}\right)^2 $$
$$ 8x > 2x + 3\sqrt[3]{x-y}\sqrt[3]{x+y} \left( \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} \right) $$
$$ 6x > 3\sqrt[3]{x-y}\sqrt[3]{x+y} \left( \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} \right) $$
$$ 2x > \sqrt[3]{x-y}\sqrt[3]{x+y} \left( \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} \right) $$
I tried cubing again, but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Anyone have any ideas, or is this a truly difficult task?

@CalvinLin yes expanding $(A+B)^3$ is fine - precalculus students should be able to do that. What I meant was, you cannot use Newton's generalised Binomial formula when expanding, for example, $(x+y)^{1/2}.$

If $0 < y < x$, then it follows that $$0 < \sqrt[3]{x-y} < \sqrt[3]{x} < \sqrt[3]{x+y},$$ and thus, $$0 < \sqrt[3]{x}^2+\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{x-y}+\sqrt[3]{x-y}^2 < \sqrt[3]{x+y}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+y}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}^2.$$ Then, since $y > 0$, we have $$0 < \dfrac{y}{\sqrt[3]{x+y}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+y}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}^2} < \dfrac{y}{\sqrt[3]{x}^2+\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{x-y}+\sqrt[3]{x-y}^2} \quad (*)$$
Finally, by using the equalities $$y = (x+y)-x = \sqrt[3]{x+y}^3-\sqrt[3]{x}^3 = \left(\sqrt[3]{x+y}-\sqrt[3]{x}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{x+y}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+y}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}^2\right)$$ and $$y = x-(x-y) = \sqrt[3]{x}^3-\sqrt[3]{x-y}^3 = \left(\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{x-y}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{x}^2+\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{x-y}+\sqrt[3]{x-y}^2\right),$$ the inequality $(*)$ simplifies to $$0 < \sqrt[3]{x+y}-\sqrt[3]{x} < \sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{x-y}.$$
EDIT: I'm not 100% sure how advanced the identity $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ is compared to the binomial theorem, but I think it might be precalculus level.

The identity is fine at the precalculus level.

This answer is very nice!

And your answer is generalisable and works for $f(x)=x^{1/n}$ for any positive integer $n.$

Depending on the audience, you could first prove the special case $x=1$ and then prove the general case by plugging in $y/x$ and clearing denominators.

Here is a slightly nuanced solution, which only uses precalculus-level reasoning, but I would not expect students to come up with this approach. I'm writing this up more because I wanted to complete the solution from OP's work.
OP's working shows us that
$$ 2\sqrt[3]{x} > \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} \Rightarrow \frac{2x}{\sqrt[3]{x-y}\sqrt[3]{x+y}} >  \left( \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} \right).  $$
The implication doesn't contradict our initial assumption, since $\frac{2x}{\sqrt[3]{x-y}\sqrt[3]{x+y}}  > 2 \sqrt[3]{x}$ and so we could draw the conclusion right from the start without any additional working, so one might think "it doesn't seem to lead anywhere".
As it turns out, we can flip this argument around to get the desired conclusion:

Assume that $ 2\sqrt[3]{x} < \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y}$.
Then OP's working (with signs flipped) gives us  $ \frac{2x}{\sqrt[3]{x-y}\sqrt[3]{x+y}} <  \left( \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} \right).$
Let $ \sqrt[3]{\frac {x^2 } {x^2 - y^2} } = r > 1$, and the above becomes $ r \times 2 \sqrt[3]{x} < \left( \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} \right).$
Clearly we can iterate this process, so $ r^n \times 2 \sqrt[3]{x} < \left( \sqrt[3]{x-y} + \sqrt[3]{x+y} \right)$ for any positive integer $n$.
Since $ r > 1$, for a large enough $n$, we get a contradiction. Thus, the assumption is false.

